# High CPU utilization in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are using WSo2 ESB 4.9.0 and our application setup is as follows.

1)Deployed mediator project which has java code to connect MQ(JMS)
2) Mediator project invokes ESB api and ESB api further invokes another ESB API asynchronously. The first api with java mediator project & second api are deployed in different servers
3) The first api has one java rest based micro service and second api has 7 micro services orchestration is done
4) Now we are frequently seeing high cpu utilizations in these two ESB servers and thread dumps are no giving any clue.

All our servers are 8GB RAM and 4 core machines.

Appreciate if anybody can guide me how to troubleshoot these problems

Answer (score 0):

With out details of the Services and configurations its difficult to give an answer. Please look at following references to troubleshoot the issue further.

- http://prabu-lk.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-monitor-thread-cpu-usage-in-wso2.html
- http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-monitor-wso2-server-cpu-usage-and.html

Comment: Thanks YCR for the response. Can you let me know what are basic details required to troubleshoot the problem. It's difficult to come to a conclusion like this with few lines of problem description but this is out first attempt on WSO2 ESB and struggling to fix the problem with thread dumps.